# Gradle build on multiple projects using single build.gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a situation where I have individual projects PROJECT_A and PROJECT_B under a common directory say   projects. My Project folder looks like

```
Project

 - PROJECT_A 
 - PROJECT_B
```

Now is it possible for me to have a single build.gradle file for building both projects.

NOTE: I don't want to have individual build.gradle files for PROJECT_A and PROJECT_B, but the gradle file can have different task for building each projects

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you can have multiple subprojects with a single build.gradle.

The project structure has two subprojects, `foo` and `bar`, and each has exactly one java class `Foo.java` and `Bar.java`. Otherwise the directory just contains the default gradle directory and scripts:

```
├── bar
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── org
│                   └── example
│                       └── Bar.java
├── build.gradle
├── foo
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── org
│                   └── example
│                       └── Foo.java
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

The single `build.gradle` file looks like this. The comments should make it clear what's happening:

```
group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

// These settings apply to all subprojects but not the root project.
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

// Get a variable for each project.
Project foo = project(':foo')
Project bar = project(':bar')

// Configure the foo project as you would in foo/build.gradle.
// Just using a misc. dependency for example purpose.
configure(foo, {
    dependencies {
        implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.13.71'
    }
})

// Configure the bar project as you would in bar/build.gradle.
// Just making bar depend on foo for example purpose.
configure(bar, {
    dependencies {
        compile foo
    }
})
```

`Foo.java` and `Bar.java` contain:

```
package org.example;

public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("Hi, I'm Foo");
    }
}
```

```
package org.example;

public class Bar {
    public Bar() {
        System.out.println("Hi, I'm Bar");
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Then you can compile the full project:

```
$ ./gradlew compileJava

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 466ms
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

Answer (score 1):

Multi-project tree - water (Main Project), (sub projects )bluewhale & krill projects.

Build layout

```
water/
   build.gradle
   settings.gradle
   bluewhale/
   krill/
```

settings.gradle

```
   include 'bluewhale', 'krill'
```

Now we rewrite the water build script and boil it down to a single line.

for more detail about multiple project build by gradle use this link as Reference [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

Comment: Do I need to have build.gradle for 'bluewhale' and 'krill' ?

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't explain how you'd handle dependencies and other configurations for each of the subprojects. I also don't think the official docs do a good job of this either. I was able to figure it out only after some trial and error.